# source map is not generated for some files

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I'm encountering an issue in my production environment that I'm trying to debug. To facilitate this process, I need to enable source maps for a project based on ScandiPWA. I've successfully built the project using the following command:

`BUILD_MODE=magento GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=true scandipwa-scripts build`

Now, I can view the source map, but it seems to be missing for the file located at:

https://github.com/scandipwa/scandipwa/blob/master/packages/scandipwa/src/util/Request/QueryDispatcher.ts

I've observed that this file is a part of the source of the page. Can someone guide me on how to enable the source map for this specific file or for all files? Your assistance is greatly appreciated. Thanks!